# My family inherited a shopping center which we have sold.I'm 73, with only $476 in income a month. My share:$119,000. Will I be taxed? Land Swap?

Tags: united-states, inheritance

I'm one of nineteen (1/19) who will receive a check for $119,000 dollars from a shopping center we inherited.

I'm 73, receive ONLY $476 Social Security a month and have NO OTHER INCOME. I also have dementia. My son has power of attorney over me in case my disease
progresses to a bad point one day.

My question is: Will I be taxed on this land?

also

if I will be taxed, if I take $ and buy property along with a home on it, Do I pay taxes? Is that a Land Swap?

Comment: How long was the period from inheritance to sale of the property. Did the value of the property increase during that time? If so, how much?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep since `19 * $119,000 = $2,261,000` wouldn't this fall well under the $5.49M/$10.98M estate tax exclusion threshold?

Comment: But if the property was inherited 10 years ago, and has increased in value, then the increase in value would be taxable, Also the 5.49Million would determine if the estate had to pay taxes, not if the recipients who later sell the property have to pay taxes.

Comment: I think this would constitute the employment of a CPA or tax attorney.  Your tax could be zero under certain conditions.